# How to access sub folders(Objects) in an AWS s3 bucket and save it into a list in python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, boto

This is my s3 Bucket

```
s3.Bucket(name='external')
```

I am using boto3.resource method :

```
s3 = boto3.resource(
    's3',
    region_name='ap-southeast-1',
    aws_access_key_id=aws_access_key_id,
    aws_secret_access_key=aws_secret_access_key
)
```

s3 folder structure is this :

```
external\product\2018\abc.csv
external\product\2019\abc.csv
external\bom\2018\csd.csv
external\bom\2019\zyc.csv
```

note that both 2018,2019 are inside product and bom too.

I tried doing this :

```
bucket = s3.Bucket(bucket)
print(bucket)
result = bucket.meta.client.list_objects(Bucket=bucket.name,
                                         Delimiter='/')
print(result)                                    
for o in result.get('CommonPrefixes'):
    print(o.get('Prefix'))
```

this only gives me :

```
product\
bom\
```

What i actualy need is the year list :

```
2018\
2019\
2018\
2019\
```

and store them two separte list Product and bom

```
Product =['2018','2019']
Bom = ['2018','2019']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few ways of doing that. One way is shown below.

Based on the following example, and assuming that the **folder structure is fixed**:

```
external\bom\2017\csd.csv
external\bom\2018\csd.csv
external\bom\2019\zyc.csv
external\product\2018\abc.csv
external\product\2019\abc.csv
external\product\2020\abc.csv
```

The following python script could work:

```
import boto3

from collections import defaultdict

session = boto3.session.Session(profile_name='<profile-name>')

bucket = session.resource('s3').Bucket('external')

key_year = defaultdict(set)

for obj in bucket.objects.all():
    key_split = obj.key.split('\\')
    key_year[key_split[1]].add(key_split[2])

for k in key_year:
    print(k, key_year[k])
```

In the script `defaultdict` and `set` are used to ensure storing unique years. The output would be:

```
bom {'2017', '2019', '2018'}
product {'2020', '2018', '2019'}
```

Comment: obj.key.split('\\') : why are you using a double \\

Comment: @Anti_cse51 Beacuse your folder names contain `\\`. You have to escape it, unlike '/'.